# Check if nested dictionary keys exist

Tags: python, dictionary

So basically I'm traversing through the nested dictionary `extension` like so:

```
extension['value1']['value2']['value3']['value4']
```

However, sometimes the dict file can be a little different:

```
extension['value1']['value2']['blah1']['value4']
```

How can I account for this scenario? I don't have to worry about a large number of scenarios, the key will only ever be `value3` or `blah1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function to get the first key that exists:

```
def get_first_item(items, keys):
    for k in keys:
        if k in items:
            return items[k]

    raise KeyError
```

And then use it like this:

```
get_first_item(extension['value1']['value2'], ['value3', 'blah1'])['value4']
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly check for the `key` and then fetch its value. For example:

```
optional_keys = ['value3', 'blah1']
value = None

for optional_key in optional_keys:
    if optional_key in extension['value1']['value2']:
         value = extension['value1']['value2'][optional_key]['value4']
         break
```

Comment: Thanks, yous both posted at basically the same time so I had to accept one and I went Ryans as it seemed a little more intuitive. I appreciate the response though, always good to have different approaches :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the above two answers can well fix your problem. Since your key will be either `value3` or `blah1`, instead of a function, you may as well use the following code when you loop through the dictionary:

```
try:
    value = extension['value1']['value2']['value3']['value4']
except Exception as e:  # except KeyError:
    # print(e)
    value = extension['value1']['value2']['blah1']['value4']
```

Comment: Considering there are just two keys which may vary, it will work.